# Insert int value of Resultset in SQL-Database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm working with a MySQL-Server and I'm trying to select an ID from another table and insert that ID in a table but it doesn't work all the time.

**Code:**

```
public void submit() throws Exception {

    Connection connection = getConnection();

    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    Statement stmt1 = connection.createStatement();

    ResultSet asset_id = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM cars.asset_type WHERE asset_type.name =" + "'" + sellables.getValue()+ "'");

    while (asset_id.next()) {
        System.out.println(asset_id.getInt("id"));
    }

    double value = parseDouble(purchased.getText());
    System.out.println(value);

    LocalDate localDate = purchased_at.getValue();

    String insert = "INSERT INTO asset (type_id, purchase_price, purchased_at) VALUES ('"+ asset_id + "','" + value +"','" + localDate +"')";
    stmt1.executeUpdate(insert);
}
```

I keep getting the same error message.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl@1779d92' for column 'type_id' at row 1
```

Comment: You do realize that `asset_id` is a `ResultSet` and not an `int`? You're reading (and throwing away) the ints in your `while` loop, and then you try to put the `ResultSet` object into your insert statement. Also, stop using `Statement` right now and move to `PreparedStatement` and its `setXXX` methods (you'll find plenty of examples with a little searching).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no value in doing two client/server roundtrips in your case, so use a single statement instead:

```sql
INSERT INTO asset (type_id, purchase_price, purchased_at)
SELECT id, ?, ?
FROM cars.asset_type 
WHERE asset_type.name = ?
```

If you really want to insert only the last ID from your `SELECT` query (as you were iterating the `SELECT` result and throwing away all the other IDs), then use this query instead:

```sql
INSERT INTO asset (type_id, purchase_price, purchased_at)
SELECT id, ?, ?
FROM cars.asset_type 
WHERE asset_type.name = ?
ORDER BY id DESC -- I guess? Specify your preferred ordering here
LIMIT 1
```

Or with the JDBC code around it:

```java
try (PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO asset (type_id, purchase_price, purchased_at) " +
    "SELECT id, ?, ? " +
    "FROM cars.asset_type " +
    "WHERE asset_type.name = ?")) {

    s.setDouble(1, parseDouble(purchased.getText()));
    s.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(purchased_at.getValue()));
    s.setString(3, sellables.getValue());
}
```

This is using a `PreparedStatement`, which will prevent [SQL injection](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/05/using-sql-injection-vulnerabilities-to-dump-your-database/) and syntax errors like the one you're getting. At this point, I really really recommend you read about these topics!

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to mention that I've heard of SQL Injections before. The thing is I will use my SQL Server for my project and it will NOT be publicised. I still appreciate help very much!

Comment: @Vince: That's what you say now. And the next developer, unaware of your assumption, will recklessly ship your code to production. Please never concatenate values to your SQL strings, regardless what for. *Never*